# pyscript print function displays then vanishes in a second

Tags: python, pyscript

I recently started using pyscript and in the  tag I have only written a print statement. On the browser the value prints but only for a second and then vanishes. I am currently using the CDN to use pyscript. Is there anything I need to be aware of?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- pyscript stuff -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <py-script>
print('order 66')
    </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with corresponding code?

Comment: sorry,  added the code now

Comment: Your example code works fine for me. The text takes a second or two to display, due to PyScript's loading time. Does the text display after you wait for a while, say 30 seconds? If not, how are you loading the page?

Comment: I run your code and it seems like it's working fine. I would check the environment you're running in it and also check the version of your browser.

Comment: Are you sure the results of the print are displaying and then going away and not the Python code?. There is an issue with Pyscript where the Python code will display for a brief period while Pyscript initializes. Once Pyscript is loaded, it hides the Python code between the tags. Your Python code will then run and display results in the DOM. Open the Chrome debugger -> Console tab and review messages.

Comment: It shows below error when trying to do a print:
Python exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, in eval_code
    .run(globals, locals)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 300, in run
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
  File "<exec>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<exec>", line 391, in write
  File "<exec>", line 116, in write
JsException: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#-15a55dd3-2ffd-41c9-026e-5c34d2ffc8b7' is not a valid selector.

Comment: I want to figure out why it is throwing DOM exception

Answer (score 1):

just put the print inside HTML tag

Answer (score 0):

There's a new function called **display()**

[Documentation](https://jeff.glass/post/whats-new-pyscript-2022-12-1/#Display)

try this instead:

```
<body>
    <py-script>
        display('order 66')
    </py-script>
</body>
```